# Optimize code to reduce number of DB hits

Tags: python, sql, database, optimization

I have a piece of code that hits the database 60-90 times for every item and its included attributes to fetch the attribute details.
Now if I add 10 items number of DB hits increases by 500-900 which makes the code slower and slower. What are some ways to optimize this?
The code goes something like...

```
for item in ITEMlist:
   for attribute in item:
       queryAttributeDataFromDB
```

I have to hit the inbuilt database tables so I don't have a local schema. And I need attribute data for each attribute in each item. Even if I thought to create some local schema I have to hit that for every attribute the item has.

Comment: Can you write a single query that fetches all the attributes for the item? (And going a step further, can you write a query that fetches all the attributes for multiple items?)

Comment: You didn't provide much information. Why not execute one query that returns all the data you need? Why do you have to execute a different query for every item and attribute?

Comment: I may try to collect all attributes in a tuple and then pass them all together to the same query instead of passing them one by one. Will that enhance performance?

Comment: Likely, yes. SQL database engines are designed to cope well with extracting data in bulk.

Comment: Let me try that. @slothrop